# Rebuild and Rerun Go application in Minikube

Tags: go, kubernetes, minikube

I'm building a micro service in Golang which is going to live in a Kubernetes cluster. I'm developing it and using Minikube to run a copy of the cluster locally.

The problem I ran into is that if I run my application inside of the container using `go run main.go`, I need to kill the pod for it to detect changes and update what is running.

I tried using a watcher for the binary so that the binary is updated on every save and a binary is running inside the pod, but even after compiling the new version, minikube is running the old one.

Any suggestion? 
Here is my deployment file for running the MS locally:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    name: pokedex
  name: pokedex
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: pokedex
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: source
          hostPath:
            path: *folder where source resides*
      containers:
        - name: pokedex
          image: golang:1.8.5-jessie
          workingDir: *folder where source resides*
          command: ["./pokedex"] # Here I tried both the binary and go run main.go
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: go-server
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: source
              mountPath: /source
          env:
          - name: GOPATH
            value: /source
```

Comment: Changing the binary file, is not going to stop a running process and restart it with a new binary.  The typical approach would be to containerize your application, since a live k8s deployment is not going to be mounting volumes from your local machine.  Once containerized, you can use a bash script to build a linux binary, build the new docker image, push it to a reposition with a custom tag (E.g. version number, commit hash or timestamp), then use kubectl update the deployment.yaml file.  While this sound like a lot of work, you only need to write such a script once.

Comment: Only addition to PassKit is you can explore wider Continuous Integration/Deployment tools (e.g. Spinnaker) for auto deploying changes. Probably of more value if when in production though.

Comment: We have CI/CD pipelines for deployments, that is not the problem.
The problem is how to handle development locally as Minikube does not detect changes to the code and doesn't restart the service when changes are applied to the source code

Comment: tl;dr: you don't want to. Minikube is NOT that development environment, where you need to re-deploy an application on each line of code change. Develop & run locally, use `kubectl proxy` or kubectl port-forward` to provide external resources to your app, and deploy to minikube only when you need to test how your app behaves in kubernetes cluster.